# Clojure equivalent of python int.from_bytes(byteorder='big')

Tags: python, clojure

The Python built in method `int.from_bytes()` returns the integer represented by the given array of bytes. I wanted know the Clojure equivalent of such method or similar methods in Clojure.

Answer (score 2):

You could use java's [java's BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(byte[])) directly:

```
(BigInteger. (byte-array [1 2 3])) 
=> 66051
```

Since clojure natively supports big numbers, you could use it seamlessly with clojure's arithmetics:

```
(def b (BigInteger. (byte-array [1 2 3])))
(+ b 23)
=> 66074N
```